Quantity of the vowels in undecies
I am reading a book where the word undecies is written with a breve sign above the i:
undecĭes.
In Wiktionay, though, it is: ūndeciēs.
Could anyone explain the difference?
Also, does undecĭes mean that the pronunciation should be undēcies?

The book where you have seen undecĭes only allows you to infer which syllable is accented (see here), not which vowels are long.
With short vowel in syllable ci, location of accented syllable must be: undecĭes.
If syllable ci had long vowel ī, then location of accented syllable would be: undecīes.
Wiktionary entry for this word correctly marks short and long vowels: ūndeciēs = /uːnˈde.ki.eːs/ = [uːn̪ˈd̪ɛkieːs̠].
(Symbol ˈ in IPA precedes accented syllable.)

Also, does undecĭes mean that the pronunciation should be undēcies?

No. Accented syllable does not need to have long vowel.

With short vowel in syllable ci, location of accented syllable must be: undecies.
Doesn't it mean I'm correct in this:
Also, does undecĭes mean that the pronunciation should be undēcies?.

@m26a Syllable de in ūndeciēs is accented, but it has short vowel. In traditional orthography, macron over vowel letter specifies long vowel (marked by ː in IPA), not accented syllable.

I see. Thank you very much. Until now I wasn't aware of the difference between accented syllable and long vowel. Now it is clear to me.
